# When using material that requests attribution, do you have to when using internally?

Tags: copyright, software, assets

[FlatIcon](https://www.flaticon.com/) requests that we add attribution (it is required according to the website). In the case of apps (my case), it states the following:

> Paste this link on the website where your app is available for download or in the description section of the platform or marketplace you’re using.

However:

- The company uses the software exclusively internally.
- There is no location to download the application like a website or marketplace. It is provided through administration.

In this case it is specifically about an icon I want to use, but I was wondering how this would apply generally.

Comment: Regardless of what you are *required* to do, it seems at least prudent to attribute internally to the extent that if, in the future, anyone would ever use it *externally* they'd know where it came from enough to know to attribute it, keeping in mind that people that work for a company now may not work there in the future.